# Create nested TypeScript type from a simple one

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I've a model that looks like this

```js
export interface LoremIpsum {

propertyA: string;
propertyB: number;

}
```

From the server I have the data returned in this format

```js
{
    "Fields": {
        "propertyA": {
            "value": "something"
        },
        "propertyB": {
            "value": 123
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a way to make the generic type for this? SO I could use it in a way like `DynamicResponse<LoremIpsum>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to iterate over all keys of the generic type `T`. You can then map each property type of `T` to `{ value: T[K] }`

```js
type Fields<T> = {[K in keyof T]: { value: T[K] }};

interface DynamicResponse<T> {
  Fields: Fields<T>
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsoQLYEkAOAzgK7bIDeAsAFDLL5Tr7RgCeAggFzKFhSgBzANw06DJi1YAhbiFIAjaCOoBfGjTbNkAMWAQANgBNCAHgAqAPmQBeCgG0A0slDIA1hFboYyMwF1u5MgAbnD6xBDcZo6+yCoqyjSgkLCIKAAirCBw2MAIAEoQhPjoIIQQ5lZUtDp6RoTcugbGFTRq1DT6EGDIkLzcGVk5+YXFpeUYWHhEpBYJ1L3dtlV0jXUBonT0jMxQbFwUG5vBoeHcAOQw6Ohnh7EANLfiO2wyB9VHIWERyAAsAEy3Np0NoqIA)